# Compare dates throws Type mismatch for Mac but not for Windows

Tags: excel, vba, macos, date

I'm trying to compare a date with the current date like this:

```vb
If CDate("11/04/2014") <= Date Then
```

The script works fine for Windows and the output is correct, but on a Macintosh it shows:

[image: Run-time error <code>13</code>]

How do I solve this?

**EDITED**

```
If DateValue("11/04/2014") <= Date Then
```

Throw me this error.
[image]

Comment: How is the MAC VBA for the [DateValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5(v=vs.90).aspx) command?

Comment: @Jeeped how do I check MAC VBA for DateValue command?

Comment: `If DateValue("11/04/2014") <= Date Then` or `?DateValue("11/04/2014")` in the *Immediate* window.